# Seems Maven Surefire is trying to connect to TestNG for running test cases after Cucumber-JVM Parallel Plugin creates Runner successfully

Tags: cucumber-jvm

**Environment - Cucumber V. 4.2.3 | Selenium V.3.8.1 | JUnit V.4.12 | cucumber-jvm- parallel-plugin V.5.0.0 | maven-surefire-plugin V.2.22.1 | maven-compiler- plugin v.3.3**

**Seems like Maven Surefire is trying to configure TestNG with created runners by Cucumber-JVM Parallel Plugin. I want to run via Junit not by TestNG. Not sure, why its connecting to TestNG.**

```
[INFO] Running TestSuite
Configuring TestNG with: TestNG60Configurator
[TestNG] [ERROR] No test suite found. Nothing to run
Usage: <main class> [options] The XML suite files to run

Configuring TestNG with: TestNG60Configurator
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.573 s - in TestSuite
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.108 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-02-18T00:28:10+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**I have mentioned useTestNg as false in cucumber jvm parallel plugin.**

**Maven Surefire Plugin Configuration**

```
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <forkCount>2</forkCount>
            <reuserForks>true</reuserForks>
            <includes>
                <include>**/Parallel*IT.class</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

**Cucumber JVM Parallel Plugin -**

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generateRunners</id>
                <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <glue>
                        <package>com.jacksparrow.automation.steps_definitions.functional</package>
                    </glue>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/cucumber</outputDirectory>
                    <featuresDirectory>src/test/resources/features/functional/</featuresDirectory>
                    <cucumberOutputDir>target/cucumber-parallel</cucumberOutputDir>

                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <name>json</name>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>

                    <useTestNG>false</useTestNG>

                    <namingScheme>simple</namingScheme>
                    <!-- The class naming pattern to use. Only required/used if naming scheme 
                        is 'pattern'. -->
                    <namingPattern>Parallel{c}IT</namingPattern>

                    <!-- CucumberOptions.strict property -->
                    <strict>true</strict>
                    <!-- CucumberOptions.monochrome property -->
                    <monochrome>true</monochrome>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Can someone guide me why Surefire is trying to configure TestNG for running generated runners and at last it says Build Successful and No Test Case gets executed. Please guide.

Comment: I came across there could be chances where surefire is trying to connect to other provider i.e. testng in my case. Can someone guide me how shall i forcefully mention junit with in surefire. is below one correct for 4.12  <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-junit412</artifactId>

Comment: Someone said in one of the post on github he was facing same problem until he had to add testng dependency. I did it as well (org.testng | testng | 6.9.4) but no luck so far and below are the Junit & TestNG dependency in my POM         io.cucumber | cucumber-testng | 4.2.3
org.testng | testng | 6.9.4
io.cucumber | cucumber-junit | 4.2.3 | <scope>test</scope>
junit | junit | 4.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was because of Dependency on testNG causes Surefire to ignore JUnit wrapper class. I removed all the TestNG dependencies or you can take a call to 2 define 2 execution - For TestNG & JUnit and disable one as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to put my 2 cents here, as this answer sent me into the right direction. I had 0 dependencies to TestNG (even the effective POM had none) and had no surefire configuration in my POM. I added a plugin in my POM configuring surefire (I googled maven surefire junit) and now the "test"-step wasn't referring to TestNG anymore.